# How to record a video from video in app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am playing a video clip on a UIView in iPad screen. In half of the screen video is playing. In other half I am doing some text animation and playing sound also.

I need to record all these (video + Text animation + audio). As all this is on same view.

I can record screen by UIScreenCapture view classes using AVAsset writer.

But it Doesn't record video playing on screen.i have played video on AVPlayer and MPMovie player controller both but AV asset writter doesn't record video from screen.

Please help.

Comment: This technica Q&A from Apple should point you in the right direction http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1714/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

About Caputring Screen i find some nice Tutorial i think it will help you.
First Tutorial Capturing Whole Screen Video and Second one guide you how to add Sound with ScreenCaputring.

[link1](http://aroth.no-ip.org:82/wordpress/archives/673)[link2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13418/how-to-play-record-edit-videos-in-ios)

Hope it will be helpful for you.Thanks

Comment: I am using already these classes for my screen capturing but these classes doesn't record video which is playing on my View.It record whole screen but at video playing area it show black screen.